# Time Machine on macOS: having updated Ventura, now cannot backup

Tags: mac-osx, apple, time-machine

I have been using a sparse bundle on an external RAID for my Time Machine backup for macOS.

However, I have just noticed that it has not been backing up since a recent update to Ventura. I can't recall what the update was to be honest!

So I tried to recall how I did this initially a year or so ago, and it involved `sudo tmutil setdestination/inheritbackup`...not actually sure.

In any event, I now cannot get the original backup sparse bundle to be used by Time Machine. My most recent effort is:

```
sudo tmutil setdestination "/Volumes/macOS 12 Time Machine"
```

...where that is the mounted volume, but this results in:

> /Volumes/macOS 12 Time Machine: APFS volumes must be empty before their first use with Time Machine. (error 45)
>
> The backup destination could not be set.

Having tried with `inheritbackup`, I am told is has successfully inherited, but the drive does not appear as an option in System Settings.

Comment: I think this question belongs in super user